# Css not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I'm new to CSS and am trying to align textboxes, labels etc for a web-form correctly using asp.net. I thought i'd managed to get everything in place however on restarting the page the boxes aren't aligned anymore and its only when I edit the CSS code whilst running the webpage that it aligns properly, does anybody know why this is/how to fix it: code is below:

```
<asp:View ID="Tab1" runat="server">
                <h2>Address details</h2>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHomeAddress" AssociatedControlID="txtHomeAddress" CssClass="Addlabel">Home Address: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHomeAddress" Columns="40" Rows="4" TextMode="multiline" CssClass="Addinput"/><br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHomePostcode" AssociatedControlID="txtHomePostcode" CssClass="Addlabel2">Home Postcode: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHomePostcode" CssClass="Addinput2"/><br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHomeOwner" AssociatedControlID="ddlHomeOwner" CssClass="Addlabel2">Home Owner: </asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHomeOwner" runat="server" CssClass="Addinput2">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="OWN_HOME">OWN HOME</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="PARENT">PARENT</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="OTHER">OTHER</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                    <br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHomePhone" AssociatedControlID="txtHomePhone" CssClass="Addlabel2">Phone Number: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHomePhone" CssClass="Addinput2"/><br />
                </p>
            </asp:View>
```

And this is the CSS

```
/*address input left*/
.Addinput {
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
float: left;
margin-left: 00px;    
}
/*address text left*/
.Addlabel {
display: inline-block;
text-align: right;
float: left;
}
/*address right input*/
.Addinput2{
float:right;
font-size:10px;
padding:4px 8px;
border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
width:280px;
margin: -10px 200px 15px;
}
/*address right text*/
.Addlabel2{
float:left;
font-size:14px;
padding:4px 8px;
width:550px;
margin:-16px 90px -20px;
}
```

And this is how it looks + how it should look

[image: How it looks]

how it should look
[image: how it looks]

Comment: "its only when I edit the CSS code whilst running the webpage that it aligns properly". So...change the source CSS files to match whatever you did on-the-fly in the browser? Changes made within the browser are just done on that one-time copy, they're not saved to the server.

Comment: It was changed within the source, I just had the page actively running alongside it

Comment: in that case do a hard refresh with Ctrl+F5 to make sure everything is refreshed and cached items are re-loaded from the server. If that doesn't fix it, then you probably made a mistake in the source files.

Comment: Solved! it somehow just corrected itself after about 20 minutes of not changing anything, which is incredibly odd